# How to fix encoding with dom

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to scrape some old pages and present them in a modern design for me using Dom

And I have a problem with the encoding, The content is in french

I am using this code to get the content that I want, There is 2 type of content "Categories" And "Data"

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->validateOnParse = true;
@$html->loadHTML($page);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$table =$xpath->query("//*[@style='background: white']")->item(0);
```

Then I process the content , First I enter the Categories in a function that convert them to id for me

```
function category_to_id($category) {
    $categories = array('Forêts','Assurance','Aéronautique','Equipement ','Autre');

    foreach ($categories as $id => $cat) {
        if(trim($cat) == trim($category)) {
            return $id + 1;
        }
}

}
```

Then I store everything in MYSQL database

My first problem is my function work only for categories without spécial charachters like Assurance

And the second is that when I go to the database, I find the data stored like this `Travaux d'Ã©lectricitÃ©` instead of `Travaux d'électricité`

I tried adding `$html->encoding = 'utf-8';` But that didn't change anything

What am i doing wrong, And how can I fix it

Comment: file encode as utf-8? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`  for example you can look this in header section.

Comment: @Naumov I am not sure I understand, The files are in HTML there is only this in the headers 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dom doesn't use UTF-8 as default, so you should encode the page to it

```
$xml->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($page, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"););
```

Alternatively, you could `utf8_decode` your string

```
echo category_to_id(utf8_decode("Travaux d'Ã©lectricitÃ©"));
```

Comment: `utf8_decode` Is the right answer, I didn't use `mb_convert_encoding` because it only remove the special charachters completely , it convert `Aéronautique` to `Aronautique`